# RAILS - FOG - request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fog

i got an issue with the connection to AWS S3 and couldnt find an answer on StackO. I did a triple Check on my Aws_Access keys / secret in my application.yml. I think I copy/paste it correctly. 
Do I need to include a Require YAML somewhere ? Maybe there is a problem of Copy/paste process , i dont really , im a bit new to this.

Here's my code :

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  config = YAML::load_file('config/application.yml')
  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => {
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :thumb => "100x100#"
      },
    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
    :url  => ":s3_domain_url",
    :path => "public/avatars/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
    :storage => :fog,
    # Configuration for Amazon S3
    :fog_credentials => {
        provider: 'AWS',
        region: 'us-west-2',
        path_style: true,
        aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
        aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
    },
        fog_directory: ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"]

    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

The Error :

> Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response :body =>
>   "\n`SignatureDoesNotMatch`The
>   request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your key and signing method.
>   ....

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE: XXXXXXX
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: AKXXXXXXBPQ
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: yXXXXXXXXggj/KXXfXXXXXzJob
EMAIL_LOGIN: xxx@gmail.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
development:
  FOG_DIRECTORY: demo-dev
production:
  FOG_DIRECTORY: demo-production
```

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: My bad I found the answer in the AWS console, the region of the 'Last Used Region' in the IAM manager console was 'eu-central-1' and not Us-west-2

Comment: Glad you were able to find a fix for yourself.

Comment: Thanks , it's always satisfaying ;)